# In notepad++, how can i copy a lot of nulls without changing it to a space on a different tab?

Tags: notepad++, binary-files

How do I copy-paste null from one tab to another tab in notepad++? It is eye-straining to input so many null values manually.

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the standard copy and paste, navigate to `Edit > Paste Special > Copy Binary Content`, then similarly use `.. > Paste Binary Content` to paste as `nul` rather than blank spaces.  To further simplify this process, I'd suggest utilizing, e.g., an .ahk script to automate and bind the process to your own preferred hotkeys.

For further details, refer to this [thread](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/10963/copy-buffer-converts-nul-to-space), but note that the post is a bit dated.